# Populating checkboxlist in UserControl took ages

Tags: asp.net, .net, user-controls, checkboxlist, webusercontrol

I created UserControl with asp.net that contains asp TextBox and asp Checkboxlist. For my control, I created the property that gets values as DataTable and then populates CheckboxList with values.

```
 Public Property DataSourceItem as DataTable
  Get
     Return CheckBoxList.DataSource
  End Get
  Set(ByVal value as DataTable)
     CheckBoxList.DataSource = value
     CheckboxList.DataTextField = value.Columns(0).ToString
     CheckboxList.DataValueField = value.Columns(0).ToString
     CheckboxList.DataBind()
  End Set
 End Property
```

And now I have a problem because if I paste eg 40 UserControls on Page it took ages to populate them with data. 
It works fine when I change control type from my UserControl to eg regular asp DropdownList.

Could someone help me to investigate this?

Comment: where do you get the datatable from? is that coming from a db? How do you past 40 controls to a page. is it from the IDE or do you clone them at runtime. do you have event handlers for each of the controls?

Comment: I get it from db. I'm creating them on runtime not clone them. No, I do not have any event handler, only Jquery on user control but it fires only on events like click.